# encoding c-language CMD windows

Tags: c, character-encoding

I have a problem with encoding in my c-programs. It seems to work fine in Eclipse but when executing the program in CMD in windows its not able to show the swedish "Å" "Ä" "Ö".

Is this because the encoding for the windows-XP is different from the encoding in my c-program.

I did query the local settings through setlocale() and I got the following:

Swedish_Sweden.1252

is there any quick solution to this?

Comment: Eclipse is probably unaware of any codepage issues at all (you could check the manual). So you are inserting the 'correct' characters into your source -- because you can see them -- but they do not match the output codepage. You will need to change the character values in your source code to get it right on the console (and hope everyone else is using the same Windows codepage you are using!).

Answer (score 0):

Use the command *change codepage*:

```
chcp 850
```

which will change the code page to Multilingual (Latin I). Make sure your font can display the characters you need.

Comment: the actual encoding was 850. I had å, ä, ö with this - but NOT in my c-programs. I changed the encoding to 65001 but it became even worse.