# Character encoding C and Swedish åöä

Tags: c, encoding, cmd

I have no idea how to solve the character encoding for the swedish letters "å" "ä" "ö".

It works fine in Eclipse where the encoding is set to Cp1252. BUT - when I execute the same program in windows CMD I can not any longer see these characters. I have tried to change the encoding in CMD to 1252 and 65001, that is: chcp 1252 and chcp 65001 ... but NOPE!

Have even tried with a library function in C called setlocale, that is:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "swedish");
```

MANY THANKS TO SUGGESTIONS THAT SOLVES THIS ISSUE!!!!!!!

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682268/encoding-c-language-cmd-windows and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how ?

Comment: Are your strings ANSII ASCII? Or multi-byte?

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "SE");
```

Comment: have you installed Swedish characters? what is the default language in your OS? The above works for me in US-en Win7 Prof with Swedish keyboard installed.